# Where does Woocommerce get the product price from?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the way woocommerce works so that instead of getting the product price in the standard way it gets the price that I feed to it via an API.

To do this I need to know where the code/function is that gets the pricing data.

This is because the company has an offline system which is going to connect to the online system to provide prices on the fly (as the company has 5 different prices for every product depending on the customer which are all stored in the offline database).

Comment: Seems like the perfect opportunity to use the [WooCommerce API](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Price Hook

Use the *woocommerce_get_price* hook to return your custom price value.

`add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);`

Inspect the product object which is injected as the second dependency of the callable function.

`function return_custom_price($price, $prod_obj) {`

Comment: Firstly, thanks for helping. So I took your advice and found this:

`function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price');
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $price = ($price[0]*2.5);
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);`

This works on the product and category pages but when added to the basket it returns a price of 0 with the error: Undefined offset: 0
Also, it generates a Trying to get property of non-object error which seems to be related to the $post->ID part

Answer (score 1):

Basic the price is simply post meta

```
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
```

Sale price, is just a different meta key. I think it is:

```
$sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true);
```

**You can also use**

```
get_sale_price( ) //returns the product's sale price.

get_regular_price( ) //Returns the product's regular price.
```